# How to read PDF form fields after Encrypt/Decrypt the PDF form using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, itext

I am using `iTextSharp` to manipulate PDF document. When I encrypt the PDF form it works well and the document becomes uneditable (used `PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(...)` method). I set the owner password at the time of encryption. Later when I read the document with the same owner password it also opened up the document.

The problem begans when I try to read form fields from that opened document. I print the count of fields inside a PDF document and it is '0'. Before encrpytion the same form shows more than 50 field counts.

So why I cannot able to get the fields anymore after encrypt/decrypt the pdf document using `iTextSharp`?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to open up the 'Encrypted PDF' in `iText RUPS` tool and it shows following error in console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.treenodes.StructureTreeNode.<init>(StructureTreeNode.java:43)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:93)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:108)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:108)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.loadKids(StructureTree.java:99)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.view.itext.StructureTree.update(StructureTree.java:75)
    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.controller.PdfReaderController.notifyObservers(PdfReaderController.java:196)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.model.ObjectLoader.doTask(ObjectLoader.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.model.BackgroundTask$2.run(BackgroundTask.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you share the PDF that shows this behavior? Did you take a look at it with iText RUPS? See http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups and take a look at the Form tab, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have installed this tool and opened the PDF it shows all the form fields on the original PDF document. But when I try to open the Encrypted PDF documnet it keep showing progress message 'Updating GUI'. Note that I have set owner password on the PDF.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. Normally, RUPS should be able to open your PDF if you've only set the owner password (not the user password). Also: RUPS should show a stack trace in the Console window if something goes wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with error on console while opening encrypted pdf document. There is nothing on console when I open original PDF.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for your support and time. I am able to read fields from encrypted PDF now. The problem is that I was mixing the encryption and flattening things. After flattening I cannot able to get the fields but after encrypt/decrypt I can.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have another question if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274129/pdf-field-format-changes-after-encrypting-the-pdf-document-using-itextsharp