# PDF Field format changes after Encrypting the PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, format, itext

I am using `iTextSharp` to manipulate PDF documents. I have to make PDF document encrypted and I am able to do it. The only problem that I am getting now is the format of form fields - they got changed.

**For example:**

I have text field of '**Integer**' type with format '**1,234.00**'. Before encrypting the format is what I have set. But after encrypting the PDF the format changes to default i.e. value becomes '**1234**'.

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**

I am using following code to set password on document:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pass"));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
        {
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
          tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(
              new PdfReader(ms.ToArray()),
              fs,
              PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA,
              null,
              "pass",
              PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING
                  | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY
            );
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
```

Comment: Are you flattening the PDF when you encrypt it? If so, see this http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-avoid-loosing-fields-format-when-flattening-a-PDF-td2159636.html

Comment: No I am not flattening the PDF. I am only encrypting it with owner password.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to set the document's password? Since you can't actually edit files and instead you need to create new files based on the original I'm guessing that for some reason the formatting is getting lost.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have updated the post with code

Comment: @mkl please help on this. Is there any relation between 'document encryption' and 'text formatting'?